# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier script.js:28

Tags: javascript

```
let field = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(field);
field.classList.add('field');

//Разбиваем блок на ячейки 
for (let i=1; i<101; i++) {
    let excel = document.createElement('div');
    field.appendChild(excel);
    excel.classList.add('excel');
}


//Даём координаты каждой ячейке
let excel = document.getElementsByClassName('excel');
let x = 1,
    y = 10;

for (let i=0; i<excel.length; i++) {
    if (x>10){
        x=1;
        y--;
    }
    excel[i].setAttribute('posX', x);
    excel[i].setAttribute('posY', y);
    x++;
}

fuction generateSnake() {
    let posX = Math.round(Math.random() * (10 - 1) + 1);
    let posY = Math.round(Math.random() * (10 - 1) + 1);
    return [posX, posY];
}


let coordinates = generateSnake();
console.log(coordinates);
console.log(coordinates[0]);
console.log(coordinates[1]);
```

Comment: Обычно в ошибке ещё указан номер строки и столбца и там всё довольно очевидно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//fuction generateSnake() {
function generateSnake() {
```

Comment: Спасибо, нужно быть очень внимательным в таких вопросах